# Put php value in html field after query has been executed

Tags: php, html, pdo

I'd like to put a value in my text boxes that I get from a php query, but when I do it the values I want to put in my text boxes are not set. Does anyone know how I could do this ?
Here is my code :

```
Nom : <input type="text" name="nom" value="<?php if(isset($nom)){echo htmlspecialchars($nom);} ?>"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Mmmmm, if values not set - then set them.

Comment: That's because `$nom` is not. You can do something like this: `...value="<?php if(isset($_POST['nom'])){ echo $_POST['nom']; } ?>"...`

Comment: This seems ok, provided $nom is set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    <?php 
    $nom = $_POST['nom'];
    if (isset($nom)){ 
        $new = htmlspecialchars($nom);
    } 
    ?>

    <input type="text" name="nom" value="<?php echo $new; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the variable $nom

```
<?php 
// If the variable in the query is $nom, then
$nom = isset($nom) ? htmlspecialchars($nom) : '';

// If $nom is a POST variable, then
$nom = isset($_POST['nom']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['nom']) : '';
?>

Nom : <input type="text" name="nom" value="<?php echo $nom; ?>"/>
```